# A function that takes a list and an Integer returns an element of the list

Tags: list, function, haskell, recursion, list-comprehension

> Write a function named `findID` that takes:
>
> - a list of pairs of (student last names (String), student ids (3-digit integers)),
> - a student name
>
> and returns:
>
> - a list of student ids that match this name.

this works:

```
findID xs m = [ snd(x) | x<-xs, fst(x) ==  m]
```

result:

```
*Main> findID [("josh",123),("becky",456)] "josh"
[123]
```

but I want to not use list comprehension. via something like this:

```
findID' (x:xs) m 
    | fst(x) == m = snd(x)
    | otherwise = findID' xs
```

what am I missing?

Comment: `filter` and `map` ?

Comment: You don't need to use parentheses around function arguments in Haskell.  Instead of `snd(x)`, you should typically use `snd x` instead.

Answer (score 3):

When you recursively call `findID'` in the otherwise, you are missing the `m` parameter.

Also note, you are only returning the first matched value, not the full list, so this new function doesn't do the correct thing.

Comment: There's also no base case for the empty list.

Answer (score 1):

Using `map` and `fitler` as @Carsten suggests:

```
import Data.String
findID :: [(String, Integer)] -> String -> [Integer]
findID xs name = map snd $ filter ((==name).fst) xs
```

Test:

```
*Main> let xs = [("Smith", 123), ("Jones", 456), ("Tran", 789), ("Smith", 012)]
*Main> findID xs "Jones"
[456]
*Main> findID xs "Smith"
[123,12]
*Main> findID xs []
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write your own recursive solution something like this will work

```
findId [] _ = []
findId ((n,i):xs) m | n==m =   i: findId xs m
                    | otherwise = findId xs m
```

Comment: Thank you all this is very helpful!